# The real cofinality of singular cardinals in $L$ under $0^\#$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Suppose that $0^\#$ exists, is there a relatively simple way to show that for any ordinal $\lambda$, if $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal in $L$ then its real cofinality is $\omega$?

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true. Let $\kappa$ be any regular cardinal in $V$, and let $\lambda=(\aleph_{\kappa+\kappa})^L$. This is a singular cardinal in $L$, because $L$ can see the sequence $\langle\aleph_{\kappa+\alpha}^L\mid\alpha\lt\kappa\rangle$ converging to $\lambda$. But the true cofinality of $\lambda$ in $V$ is $\kappa$, since it is the supremum of an increasing $\kappa$ sequence of ordinals and $\kappa$ is regular.

Comment: Joel, that is interesting. The OP and myself have an assignment (we have taken the same course) in which a question is given: Assume $0^\#$ exists, if $\alpha$ is a cardinal in $L$ and its true cofinality is uncountable then it is a Silver indiscernible. From since Silver indiscernibles are inaccessible in $L$, since this means that that if $\alpha$ is a singular cardinal in $L$ and its true cofinality is uncountable, then it is inaccesible in $L$ and therefore singular, it means that the true cofinality must be $\omega$. So what you are saying implies that the question is flawed?

Comment: This question as stated is flawed, but it can be repaired if you add that $\alpha$ is a cardinal in $V$. In other words, the true statement would be: if $\alpha$ is a cardinal in $V$ and singular in $L$, then it must have true cofinality $\omega$, for otherwise it would be a Silver indiscernible and therefore inaccessible in $L$ and therefore regular in $L$.

Comment: Many thanks, Joel, I will notify him of the mistake.

Comment: The question was now corrected, I hope you did not mind I gave you credit for the counterexample. Many many thanks!

Comment: @Asaf, of course that is fine. By the way, for the future, I would usually think of questions about $0^\sharp$ and similar topics as rising to MathOverflow-level.

Comment: As I am not the OP this is not my decision where to post it, however I feel that these are borderline questions. In MO they might be appreciated but at least at this point they are certainly not research level questions. Since I am trying to get some volume into the advanced set-theory related tags on MSE I always prefer it first for these borderline questions.